# Как заставить вводить текст с большой буквы

Tags: android, android-edittext

Во многих приложениях при фокусе на пустом `EditText` клавиатура открывается в верхнем регистре для первой буквы. Каким образом можно сделать подобное?

Answer (score 4):

В тэг `EditText` добавьте

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```